# Display tree data using AG Grid in Angular project

Tags: angular, treeview, ag-grid-angular

I have json data which I want to display using AG grid inside my angular project.
the json is in following format:

```
[
{ "id": "1", "name": "root", parentId:""},
{ "id": "2", "name": "child1", parentId:"1"},
{ "id": "3", "name": "child2", parentId:"2"},
{ "id": "4", "name": "child3", parentId:"2"}
.
.
.{},{},{},{},...{}
]
```

It has a heirarchy with parent and child nodes, which I want to display in tree format.
Read documentation of AG Grid and tried the example but I did not undertstand how it works. I have been able to display data in simple row column format but not with tree format.

Answer (score 1):

For AG-Grid, to show data as a tree, you should first set **treeData: true** of GridOptions. Then you should provide the **getDataPath** method to grid know how to traverse tree data.

Also, your data should have something like hierarchicalPath. I'll show how you create hierarchicalPath of your data. (**Notice hierarchicalPath format**)

```
[
{ "id": "1", "name": "root", parentId:"", hierarchicalPath: "00001"},
{ "id": "2", "name": "child1", parentId:"1", hierarchicalPath: "00001.00001"},
{ "id": "3", "name": "child2", parentId:"2", hierarchicalPath: "00001.00001.00001"},
{ "id": "4", "name": "child3", parentId:"2", hierarchicalPath: "00001.00001.00002"}
.
.
.{},{},{},{},...{}
]
```

And minimum gridOptions for showing data in tree format:

```
  gridOptions: GridOptions = {
        treeData: true,
        getDataPath: (data) => {
            return data.hierarchicalPath.split('.');
        }
    };
```

Comment: ok but how can I programatically create the path variable (with the parent child names in the path for example: [root , child1], [child1 , child2, child3] ) and then use it in the  getDataPath method? what would be the best way?